# How does Pycharm handle virtual enviroments and their variables set in activate script?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

I'm running into an issue in pycharm. I'm using a virtual enviroment and I have added the following line to my activate script

```
source /home/me/environment.sh
```

environment.sh only contains some lines with exports for variables such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
export USERNAME="GUY"
```

When I run the python interpreter from the terminal in pycharm, I am able to see these variables by printing out

`os.environ`

However if I attempt to run any python script in my project using the actual *run* button in Pycharm, these variables are not available. I have checked the run/debug configuration and everything looks correct and it is using my venv interpreter. I do see that I can manually enter these variables into the run configuration, but why would it not be recognizing them from my active virtual environment?

Comment: Which tool do you use to create the virtual environment?

Comment: Virtual environments exist independently from shells. The "activation" script is just a convenience for using a virtual environment inside an interactive shell. It's not a necessary part of the virtual environment, is isn't used at all by the virtual environment itself. Using the virtual environment just means using the interpreter its associated with (typically `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python3`). That's all PyCharm run configurations do.

Comment: @Brian61354270 That makes sense. So Pycharm must be automatically running the activation script in the IDE terminal once the project is loaded, however this doesn't happen when just running a file directly from the IDE.